# Failed to use partClone program to save or restore an image

Tags: ubuntu, partition, data-recovery, clonezilla

I want to clone a Windows partition of a dual booted laptop which doesn't boot anymore as described [in the following link](https://superuser.com/questions/1251693/windows-dual-booted-device-dont-start-anymore).

I don't know why but I can't clone a partition with `Clonezilla`. I only have these information as displayed in below screenshot I attached here :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you press space to select the disk in step 2?  It's not sufficient to have had the red block cursor there, you need to have a `*` or `x` inside the relevant `[ ]` i think.

Comment: @sourcejedi, You're damn right !
Now I have another issue, I am changing the question

Comment: Tricky.  BTW try not to edit like that in future.  That was a reasonable Q/A pair, but now it's erased.  You can always add a comment to link people to a new question.  You might get slightly better diagnostics & advice if you try to boot a normal live media and mount the windows filesystem.  If you were mainly trying to rescue data files, that could be just as useful.

Comment: @sourcejedi ho... sorry ... I thought the question so dumb when I realised my error. I have an ubuntu live key but I don't know how to mount the windows filesystem to rescue my windows part data files

Answer (score 1):

Do you **must** use `clonezilla`? If not give out a try on these few methods,

**Method 1** - ***By using terminal commands***

1. Boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD and open the disk management tool (or use `sudo fdisk -l` from the terminal) to find out which disk you will be copying.
2. Mount the external device you will save the *.img* file to, **do not mount the disk you want to make the image from!** (**Disk you write into**)
3. Use `dd if=/dev/sda of=foo_file.img`, replace */dev/sda* with the actual disk you want to copy and *foo_image.img* with a file located in the external disk you previously mounted.
4. Reboot your PC removing the disk you made the image from and install the new disk in your PC. Boot the computer with the Ubuntu LiveCD.
5. Mount the external disk that contains the *.img* file and open the disk tool to make sure about the device where we are going to write it to. (*Probably will be using the same device path as the one you just removed*). **Don't even try to mount the new disk, there should be nothing to mount anyways!**
6. Use `dd if=foo_file.img of=/dev/sda` to write the image you created and stored in to the external device in to the new disk you just installed.
7. Run `gparted` and resize your newly created partitions to accommodate the extra space in your new disk.
8. Reboot and boot using your new disk.

(This method is by *Bruno Pereira* from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119791) )

**Method 2** - ***you can check below links***

[Link 1 -HowtoGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)

[Link 2 - AddictiveTips](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-disk-image-clone-hard-disk-partition-with-ubuntu-live-usb/)

[Link 3 - Ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997572)

[Link 4 - Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/forums/ubuntu/use-ubuntu-clone-windows-hard-drive-ntfs)

[Link 5 - edoceo](http://edoceo.com/exemplar/ntfsclone-transfer-windows)

[Link 7  -dimitar.me](http://dimitar.me/clone-disk-drives-with-ubuntu/)

Hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: Okay so 1. I have to create a `foo_image.img` file in my new HDD and 2. It will take some time before `dd` fully copied it, isn't it ?

Comment: And why can't I use `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` ? With `sda` my old Windows partition and `sdb` my new hard drive ?

Comment: I did it today, yet I am not able to reset my pc, it shows me an error.
I think I have to erase it all on my laptop, download windows again and dual boot it ...

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and partclone was already installed on my device. I used the nogui option under expert mode to get rid of GUI in order to see where the source of the error was. Turns out that I was missing the package for the compression algorithm I choose (parallel bzip2: package was lbzip2). Abscense of lbzip2 was crashing partclone because I asked for it but it wasn't there. Make sure you're not running into a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it on other system by installing only partclone:

Ex:First you need to extract the image locally use partclone:

```
sudo apt install partclone
```

then extract to image:

```
cat sda3.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.a* | gzip -d -c | sudo partclone.restore -W -o sda3.img -L partclone.log
```

then mount it:

```
sudo mount -o loop  -t ntfs sda3.img /mnt
```

Comment: There are many reasons why partclone can fail while being still installed...